# How to find External ID of contact sobject?

Tags: integration, contact, sobject, externalid

I am looking into doing a web-to-lead integration with a Drupal website. As I understand it, to push data to a salesforce sobject I need to identify the relevant fields in Salesforce which are being used for External ID.

I am looking at the fields page of the contact sobject (App setup > Customize > Contacts > fields), but for the life of me can't work out how to identify which fields function as External IDs.

Is it the case that, as a standard sobject, does Contact come with predefined External ID fields or do I need to define them myself? If I need to define them myself, can I do this on a standard field? For example, Contact has a standard email field called 'email', but I can't see any option to mark it as an External ID.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You should create it yourself. [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm&language=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking at the fields page of the contact sobject (App setup > Customize > Contacts > fields), but for the life of me can't work out how to identify which fields function as External IDs.

External Id fields are marked as (External) in the field's data type.

> Is it the case that, as a standard sobject, does Contact come with predefined External ID fields or do I need to define them myself?

No standard or custom objects come prepackaged with an External Id; you must always define your own.

> If I need to define them myself, can I do this on a standard field? For example, Contact has a standard email field called 'email', but I can't see any option to mark it as an External ID.

No, only custom fields can be used as External Id fields. You may simply want to use a custom email field to match up on, and you can copy it via Process Builder to the standard field, for emailing purposes.